# Collision Detection with Raycast in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is about as simple as it sounds. I'm trying to use a raycast to determine if a player is on the ground in a 2D Unity Game. My code is this:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up, 40, World);
if (hit.collider != null)
{
        print("touching");
}
```

I also have a `public LayerMask World;` up above and the layer "World" is set on the object I want to detect collisions to.
I'm pretty new to this so I'm not sure why the raycast isn't working.

Comment: did you check in the documentaiton the rigidbody and collider components needed for the physic interaction to take place? I would check if the componenets are according to that

Comment: And what if you change your mask to everything but world does it work then?

Comment: If I remove the 40 or World the raycast returns that it is touching something even when there are no collisions. I'm also not using a rigidbody, I have a circle collider 2D and I'm moving through code like this: `this.transform.position += Vector3.left * this.speed * Time.deltaTime;`

Comment: I did some more debugging and determined that the raycast is hitting the player object even though the player object is on the layer "Ship" and the object I'm trying to detect a collision on is on the layer "World".

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking "Queries start within collider" in the setting solved the issue.